# Partitioning results

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a table of lengths that I want to aggregate using ORACLE SQL, based on a grouping of similar columns, but I also want to partition similar groupings if they are 'split vertically' in the table rows by other non-similar data for the first two columns.

Here's some example data that hopefully explains the situation -

```
Room1   Room2    Length
A       A        1
A       A        1.5
B       B        3
B       B        1
A       A        2
A       A        3
```

I would like the results to be -

```
Room1   Room2    Agg_Length
A       A        2.5
B       B        4
A       A        5
```

When I try to achieve the above with any standard grouping arrangement, I always end up with a single line for the A/A data, with an aggregate length of 7.5, but I think I should be able to partition the data somehow so that I can end up with the three-line results above, but have no experience in doing so.

I have tried to find an existing solution to similar partitioning problems on this site, but have been unsuccessful.

Any help with the above would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: In future postings, please use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. For more info see  and [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so you need a column that specifies that ordering.  Let me assume such a column has a name, say `id`.

If so, you can accomplish what you want in several different ways.  One method is the difference of row numbers:

```
select room1, room2, sum(length)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by room1, room2 order by id) as seqnum_rr,
      from t
     ) t
group by room1, room2, (seqnum_rr - seqnum)
order by min(id);
```

To see why this works, it helps to run the subquery and stare at the results.  You should be see why the difference of the row numbers identifies the adjacent rows with the same values.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that delivers the solution I was initially after superbly. As you suggest, I can see from the subquery results why this works overall. I have a further related question, which I hope you might also be able to help with, but I'll need a little more time to compose it correctly. Thanks again for this initial solution. Kind Regards.

Comment: Hi Gordon, as discussed above, your initial solution gave me a great answer to pursue further development work, but which has now raised a further question which I hope you can help with.

Comment: The ordered results from your query need to be further worked on with more SQL working on the partitioned 'view', but the further work then requires for the partitioned 'view' to be kept in the same order as your code delivers, but though your inner-select statement above actually contains three sets of ordered columns that I could possibly use to do this (id / seqnum / seqnum_rr), I cannot find a way to deliver any of those columns by using the SQL in your great initial reply, as it seems to be needing a 'group by' statement at the end that removes everything except the partitioned data.

Comment: Is there a way for me to maintain any type of ordered column in addition to the partitioned data that your SQL originally provides?

Comment: @Martin . . . I don't understand your comment.  My first reaction is that of course you can add a column into your table that represents any ordering you want.

Comment: Apologies, I can't have explained the issue very well.

Comment: When the results are currently like this (and this is great!) - 

`code Room1   Room2    Agg_Length
    A       A        2.5
    B       B        4
    A       A        5`

I would like the results to also include some sort of order-column - 

`code Room1   Room2    Agg_Length  Order
    A       A        2.5      1
    B       B        4         3
    A       A        5         5`
 
The contents of the order-column could be any one of id/seq_num/seqnum_rr, but I am struggling to group/partition again if I do include one of them. Apologies again, and sorry for poor formatting.

Comment: ......Hi Gordson, I'm not sure I explained my issue any better in the Jan 28th comments? Is there anything else unclear as to why I would like to pass-through one of the order-columns we're using in the inner-view? Many thanks for any help you can offer. Kind Regards.

Comment: @Martin . . . All the columns in the original data are returned by the subquery.  You have to use an aggregation function -- say, `min()` or `max()` -- but you can order by them.

Comment: .......Hi Gordon, firstly, thanks for your continued support and obvious patience with this recent query, but I'm still not sure that I've explained myself well enough. I am aware that the subquery contains the original order data, and also returns the additional 'seqnum' and 'seqnum_rr' data, but the issue I have is that outside of the subquery, I cannot return any of the three different types of order fields, because doing so breaks the 'group by' function, which is needed to sum the lengths. (cont)

Comment: ....(cont) Is there any way I can maintain the original outer query, including the grouping/sum process, but also return 'some' type of order field from the inner query, for the grouped output? I don't mind which original order field could be used, so long as it's in 'some' sort of order, so I can then go on to manipulate this output further, in a way that does need some sort of original order to be maintained? I do appreciate your help and patience with this issue. Kind regards.

Comment: ..........Gordon - just to say that I've been giving your comment regarding a further aggregation function, such as min() or max(), a go today, and I have now managed to combine the aggregation functions I needed, to enable me to maintain an ordered column of data in the external query. I am really grateful for your support with this issue, and I am now able to completely fulfil my original ambition with the processes that you've helped me tackle. With great thanks - Martin